# Is the bit encoding format for the graphic in BIP 68 implicitly little-endian?

Tags: transactions, script, utxo, locktime, checklocktimeverify

**CLTV** (OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY - absolute locktime) and **CSV** (OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY - relative locktime) utilize **BIP 68**. Is the locktime for those two operations implicitly encoded in little-endian format?

Byte swapping associated with endianess has a very serious impact on the semantics for lock types (i.e., absolute, relative) and locktime value units (i.e., block number, seconds). Would it be prudent/responsible for the BIP 68 Standard to make it clear whether the bit-encoding is natively little-endian or big-endian?

Answer (score 2):

All fields in a Bitcoin transaction are little-endian encoded except for the signature fields and the public key fields which are both DER and big-endian encoded since they were originally produced by an external library that uses these encodings.

> Would it be prudent/responsible for the BIP 68 Standard to make it
>   clear whether the bit-encoding is natively little-endian or
>   big-endian?

I think this information belongs in the [protocol documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx), not necessarily in the BIP.