# What are the correct "threshold" values of the nSequence in order to activate relative time lock and only absolute time lock?

Tags: locktime, sequence

Based on [BIP68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0068.mediawiki), relative lock time is activated if the most significant bit in `nSequence` value is **not** set. In other words, if the 32th (1<<31) bit is not set. So for the `nSequence` values less-equal than:

1. `01111111111111111111111111111111` in binary
2. `0x7FFFFFFF` in hexadecimal

... relative lock time is activated.

However, in the `Ugam Kamat's` [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/87376/145749), he said that the relative lock time is activated for a `nSequence` values less than `0xEFFFFFFF`.

> If `nSequence <= 0xEFFFFFFF`, it implies relative locktime.

**1. How is it possible? What is correct upper value to activate relative time lock?**

Also, for activating just an absolute lock time without relative lock time, he said in his [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/88290/145749) that the nSequence must be between `0xF0000000` and `0xFFFFFFFD` (to also activate RBF).

> So for using `nLocktime` along with Opt-in RBF, your `nSequence` value has to be between 0xF0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFD.

However, based on [BIP68](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0068.mediawiki), to deactivate relative lock time it is only necessary to **set** most significant bit (32th bit) in the `nSequence`. So for the `nSequence` values greater-equal than:

1. `10000000000000000000000000000000` in binary
2. `0x80000000` in hexadecimal

... relative lock time is not activated.

**2. What is the smallest value we can set for `nSequences` so that only the absolute lock time is activated without the relative one?**

Comment: I assume this is just a typo/thinko in Ugam's answer.

Comment: @PieterWuille Okay, what would be the correct answer for example for the first question? I would say `0x7FFFFFFF` and he said `0xEFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @PieterWuille I think that confusion also comes from the way BIP68 is written. Since the Bitcoin uses little endian then the picture in this BIP can be assumed also as `11111111111111111111111111111110`, that is `FFFFFFFE`. So most right bit is 0, since it is most significant bit in the case of little endian. Also, since hexadecimal does not have anything with endian it is `0xFEFFFFFF`. However, for me it is more correct `01111111111111111111111111111111`, that is `7FFFFFFF`. In hexadecimal `0x7FFFFFFF`.

Comment: @PieterWuille Almost 5 years ago, `skaht` in his [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83486/is-the-bit-encoding-format-for-the-graphic-in-bip-68-implicitly-little-endian?rq=1) pointed to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 << 31` is unambiguous. It means set the 31st bit (counting from the least significant bit). How that is represented in memory is irrelevant as numbers always have a least significant bit (0) and a most significant bit.

This means that `0x7fffffff` is the threshold in big endian.

Comment: "`1 << 31` is unambiguous. It means set the 31st least significant bit." Doesn't `1<<31` mean setting the **most** significant bit, not the **least** significant bit?

Comment: `<<` represents left push. Since you are pushing 31 times, you are setting most left bit and it is most significant bit?

Comment: `1 << 31` is setting the 31st bit, starting from the least significant one. Is that clearer?

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, that's clearer. In other words, it means setting the most significant bit, that is the most left one?

Comment: @LeaBit Whether that's the left or the right one depends on your notation. In C-like language parlance, a "left shift" is by definition a multiplication by two, so leftmost there means most significant. But in most computer hardware representations, the least significant bytes come first.

Comment: @PieterWuille I do not want to complicate and waste your time, so the answer on the first question is `0x7FFFFFFF` and on the second is `0x80000000`?

Comment: @LeaBit I believe so.